# Azure Web job disappeared in app instance

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

We have web job running in app instance. This is shared for a .net core web api  app as well and other team is deploying web app to this same app servcie  .

We can see the web job  is not there now ? .

is this because of the web app deployment deleted the web job ?

can we deploy and web app in to appservice with out destroying a web job ?

is it better to have dedicated app service for web job?

Please give some pointers on  the above questions.

Comment: while deploying to azure if we check "Remove additional files are destination" in file publish options , then we can see the web job also get deleted

Comment: Glad that your issue got resolved. Please post it as an answer, so that it can be useful for other community members.

Answer (score 0):

While deploying to azure, if we check "Remove additional files are destination" in file publish options, then web job also will be deleted.